# Insert a node in the middle of a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I have to build a function where its purpose is to insert a node before/after an iter position that is managed by the DequeIterator class. In order to do that, I have to link all the pointers to the right positions to make them connected to each other, and yet, I'm having problem linking all the pointers to the right node.

For example, if I have a doubly linked list of node A, B, D, E and my iter is points to the node D at the moment, and I want to insert a node C before node D. Can anyone help me out ? Thank you

```
// iter will be an object from the DequeIterator.
void insert_before(DequeIterator<E>& iter, E x)
{
        // make sure the list is not empty
        // since I have a function insert_front already        
    assert(!is_empty());
        // create a temp pointer to hold node D 
    DNode<E>* temp = iter.node();
        // create a new node C, with its prev points to (D->prev)
        // and its next points to node C
    DNode<E>* temp2 = new DNode<E>(iter.node()->prev(), x, iter.node());

        // I know that I still have 2 more pointer to link
        // but I do not know how to get it connected from
        // node B to node C and node C to node D.
    iter.node()->next() = temp2;  // I attempted to do this, but it gave me an error

    _size++;
}
```

This is the error I've got

```
Error   1   error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value e:\fall 2013\cpsc 131\linkeddeque\linkeddeque\main.cpp  312
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I did put in the error that I've got. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that the function `next()` in `iter.node()->next()` returns by value. This results in the compiler making a temporary copy (which is an rvalue) of the result. Due to its temporary nature you cannot assign another value to it.

To solve your problem you should change the signature of the `next()` function, so that it returns a reference to (the pointer to) the next node:

```
DNode<E>*& next();
```

It is good practice to also include a `const` version:

```
DNode<E>* const& next() const;
```

This allows you to retrieve the `next()` node even when working with `const DNode<E>`'s.

Comment: what if you can only pass it by value, is there any workaround to do it if not using pass by reference ?

Comment: You can always assign `iter.node()->next()` to a local variable first. However that would not result in the correct semantics, since you really want the pointer in the next field of `iter.node()` to be changed (and not some copy that happens to be lying about).